# Firebase equalTo() not fetching desired results

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase. Where I need to fetch the record for a particular attribute. But when I have used the Firebase query method, I'm unable to get the actual result. Following is my code:

```
Firebase ref = ZopOrderingAplication.getFirebaseInstance();
Firebase retailerMastRef = ref.child("Retailer_Master");
```

Here s the query I'm using:

```
Query queryRef = retailerMastRef.orderByChild("user_name").equalTo("8105409301","user_name");
```

Here is the function I'm using to fetch the records:

```
queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                long getChildCount = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                Log.i(TAG,"getChildCount: "+getChildCount);

                //Retailer_Master retailerObj = dataSnapshot.getValue(Retailer_Master.class);

                //Log.i(TAG,"retailer phone queryRef: "+retailerObj.getPhone());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Here is the data in my firebase databse:
[image]

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for suggestion. will replace it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to try **this**:

```
Query queryRef = retailerMastRef.orderByChild("user_name").equalTo("8105409301");
```

Remove **user_name** from equalTo() as you have it in orderByChild.

Hope this helps. Do let me know if it changes anything for you.

Comment: Yes that is working but is there any groupby option to fetch only original records instead of fetching the duplicate records?

Comment: Please give me an example that explains your issue or share a json. What do you mean by original records ?What will be the property of original records ? Give me something more to help you properly .